# Use `\leftmark` also in headers of odd pages (instead of `rightmark`)

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I have a problem where one chapter in my book has no sections, and in that case I want the chapter name to appear on both even and odd pages in the headers. How do I achieve that in an easy way? Since I'm using `memoir` I tried the following

```
\makeoddhead{headings}{\leftmark}{}{\thepage}
```

but then I got into a weird problem of the header not working on the very last page before next chapter.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

How to make this work on a specific chapter only?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Not on this chapter ...}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{... but on THIS chapter}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
\makeatletter
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
\makeatother
```

`\chapter` sets both a left and a right mark.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter without Sections}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter with Sections}
\section{Section}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way of making this work for a specific chapter only? I've updated the MWE accordingly.

Comment: Never mind, managed to solve that by defining a new page style (using `\copypagestyle`) and then applying it before the `\chapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing `\renewcommand` to `\chaptermark` will address it．Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{CHAPTER\ \thechapter.\ #1}}
        {\MakeUppercase{CHAPTER\ \thechapter.\ #1}}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chaptertest}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should not be using fancyhdr with memoir. Memoir has its own system for dealing with headers and footers which is more well integrated into the class than what fancyhdr can offer.

Comment: @daleif Alright. We can also do it without using fancyhdr, as I've edited above.

Comment: Which is what esdds answer does plus more. Note what happens when if you add `\frontmatter ` at the beginning of your mwe, then compare what esdds solution does. There is a lot hidden inside that `\createmark ` construction